# Swisscom Application Cloud: External File System (Volume Services)

Tags: swisscomdev

Is it possible to use [External File System (Volume Services)](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/using-vol-services.html) on Swisscom Application Cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment not.

It's not planed yet but definitely on the radar. The App Cloud squats had a internal Hackathon and made a PoC of Volume Services (with NetApp).